# select query inside while loop in sql server php pdo

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Can you help me please..

i have a problem with my php pdo query select in SQL Server, i want to select table **PPN_IN** with FK **NO_REG** inside while loop from table name **FAKTUR**. For a one record from table **FAKTUR**, it success execute, but if more than one record on table **FAKTUR** which is have relation between table **PPN_IN** and **FAKTUR**, query select just execute one record, 
and should be followed with a number of records from the loop

and the following my sample code below,

```
$quDetailFaktur = "SELECT * FROM faktur WHERE is_public=:is_public AND session_key=:session_key ORDER BY faktur_id ASC";
$qu_rekan = $DB_con1->prepare($quDetailFaktur);
$qu_rekan->execute(array(
    ":is_public" => 0,
    ":session_key" => $session_key
));
while($dtfakturdetail = $qu_rekan->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    $stmt_ppn = $DB_con1->prepare("SELECT * FROM PPN_IN WHERE NO_REG=:noreg_ppn");
    $stmt_ppn->execute(array(
        ":noreg_ppn" => $noRegPPN
    ));
    $dt_ppn = $stmt_ppn->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 

    echo $dt_ppn->NO_REG;
}
```

with a pleasure who can help me, thank you :)